# How to integrate on_message with sqlite3 in discord.py?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I made an `on_message` event that gives you role whenever you mention 3 people in a specific channel , Now I am trying to integrate it with database so it can be used on multiple guilds.

What I've write:

```
class ScrimsCog(commands.Cog, name='Scrims-Commands') :

        def __init__(self,bot):
            self.bot = bot
    
        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_message(self,message):
            db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id}")
            result =  cursor.fetchone()
            if result is None:
                return
            else:
                cursor.execute(f"SELECT role FROM main WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id}")
                if not channel.id == channel_id:
                    return
                if len(message.mentions) >= 3:
                    await message.add_reaction(emoji="<a:tick:748476262640779276>")
                role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=role)
                user = message.author
                await user.add_roles(role)
            await self.bot.process_commands(message)
            

        
        
        @commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
        async def scrimsmod(self,ctx):
            await ctx.send('Available Setup Commands: \nscrimsmod channel <#channel>\nscrimsmod role  <message>')
        @scrimsmod.command()
        async def channel(self, ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel):
            if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
                db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute(f"SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
                result =  cursor.fetchone()
                if result is None:
                    sql = ("INSERT INTO main(guild_id, channel_id) VALUES(?,?)")
                    val = (ctx.guild.id, channel.id)
                    await ctx.send(f" Default Registration Channel has been set to {channel.mention}")
                elif result is not None:
                    sql = ("UPDATE main SET channel_id = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
                    val = (channel.id, ctx.guild.id)
                    await ctx.send(f"Default Registration Channel has been updated to {channel.mention}")
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                db.commit()
                cursor.close()
                db.close()

        @scrimsmod.command()
        async def role(self, ctx,role: discord.Role):
            if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
                db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute(f"SELECT role FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
                result =  cursor.fetchone()
                if result is None:
                    sql = ("INSERT INTO main(guild_id, role) VALUES(?,?)")
                    val = (ctx.guild.id, role)
                    await ctx.send(f"Default role to give on correct registration have been set to `{role}`")
                elif result is not None:
                    sql = ("UPDATE main SET role = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
                    val = (role, ctx.guild.id)
                    await ctx.send(f"Default role to give on correct registration have been updated to  `{role}`")
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                db.commit()
                cursor.close()
                db.close()
    

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(ScrimsCog(bot))
    print("Scrims cog is loaded!")
```

From now I think the problem is with `on_message` part, the `channel.id` , `channel-id`, `role` are undefined but even if I define them it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to define the guild id , channel id and then how to match them with the ids in the database , that on_message part is throwing all the errors , inshort syntax of on_message is all messed up @nurqm

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do with this code. Do you want to give a certain role to the.users that mentioned 3 people and this will for every guild? Why do you need a database?

Comment: Yup you are right I want to give role to every user who mentions three people, I need db because role will only be given if the user mentions in a specific channel and  also specific role will be given . So I have to keep a record of what role the bot will give for message for that particular guild. @nurqm

Answer (score 0):

f-string maybe causing problems, try this..

```
cursor.execute("SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = ?", [message.guild.id])
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, if you connect to the database under the `on_message` event, this this reduces the efficiency of your bot. And for the other problems, you have to change the commands parameters like these

`async def channel(self, ctx, channel):`, `async def role(self, ctx,role):`

instead of these `role: discord.Role` `channel: discord.TextChannel`.

Then, when you want to call the channel or the role, you must use `discord.utils.get`,

for channels:

`await ctx.send(f"Default Registration Channel has been updated to {discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name=channel).mention}")`

for roles:

`await ctx.send(f"Default role to give on correct registration have been updated to  {discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role)}")`

So when the users using the `role` or `channel` commands, they must write the exact channel.

And when you comparing the channel id with the database, you can also use `discord.utils.get` like this:

`channel_in_database = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name="in here, you need to connect to the database and take the channel name for this guild.")`

then, `if not channel_in_database.id == ctx.channel.id:`, or maybe you can(I'm not 100% sure that will work) take the channel name from database for that guild and do:

`if "channel name from the database" == ctx.channel.name`

If one of these raises any problem or if you still have unanswered problems, just comment